# How to find a square in a measurable set with positive measure?

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Let $E \subset \mathbb{R}^{2}$ be a measurable set with positive measure $($i.e. $m(E)>0).$ The question is to show that we can find four points in E such that the four points are the vertexes of a square.

I was trying to prove that the Lebesgue integral $\int f$
is positive, where $f = \chi_{E}$ $\chi_{E+(a,b)}$ $\chi_{E+(-b,a)}$ $\chi_{E+(a-b,a+b)}$, so that there exists a pair $(a,b)$ such that $E\cap E+(a,b) \cap E+(-b,a) \cap E+(a-b,a+b)$ is nonempty, but I'm stuck here.

It is known that if $E \subset \mathbb{R}$ is a measurable set with positive measure in $\mathbb{R}$, then $E-E$ contains an interval. Is there any relation between the fact and the question?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT:

Assume that $E$ is a measurable subset and  $S$ a square  such that $m(E\cap S) > \frac{3}{4} m(S)$. Wiggle $E$ to $E_i =E+ v_i$, $i=1,4$, ($v_i$ vertices of a small square) such that we still  have $m(E_i \cap S) > \frac{3}{4} m(S)$.  Show that the $E_i$ have a common point (in $S$). What can you conclude?

Comment: Thank you very much! It seems that we can use this method to find n points which are the vertexes of any given n-polygons.

Comment: You are very welcome! Yes, indeed,  a subset similar to a given finite set.